# Multi Languge picklist values on visuaforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, picklist

I have a picklist field and a for.com site where i am rendering the picklist values.Now as the site is multi lingual i want to render the localized picklist values based on the portal user language.

Can any only give me some inputs on this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say you are already rendering the picklist values I assume your controller looks something like this

```
public List<SelectOption> getLanguage() {
        List<SelectOption> LangOptions = new List<SelectOption>();    
        LangOptions.add(new SelectOption('en_US','English'));
        LangOptions.add(new SelectOption('fr','French'));    
        LangOptions.add(new SelectOption('de','German'));           
        return  LangOptions;
    }
```

If that's the case, create labels for every language and then change your method to something like this.

```
public List<SelectOption> getLanguage() {
        List<SelectOption> LangOptions = new List<SelectOption>();            
        LangOptions.add(new SelectOption('en_US',System.Label.English));
        LangOptions.add(new SelectOption('fr',System.Label.French));    
        LangOptions.add(new SelectOption('de',System.Label.German));           
        return  LangOptions;
    }
```